# While doing Akeeba backup, unable to set Database Table Exclusion

Tags: akeebabackup

I am using Joomla 1.5.18 and Akeeba backup for many years. Recently, while I doing the normal Full Site backup, I found nothing backup.

And the Database Table Exclusion, shown RED marked, which means ALL tables are excluded. ( see attached photo )

Please tell me how to resolve it? Many thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version of Akeeba Backup for your version of Joomla and PHP which will probably be Akeeba Backup 3.6.2. See https://www.akeebabackup.com/compatibility.html to check for the correct version.

Then try resetting all filters.

I should point out (and you probably already know) Joomla 1.5 has been unsupported since 2012. At the very least (unless there is some compelling reason not to) you should upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26 and install the two end of life patches that can be found at: https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions

Answer (score 1):

Are you using shared hosting? Given the age of Joomla 1.5 and the deprecated code within it, there's every chance that your PHP version or shared hosting setup has changed, affecting the operation of Akeeba backup. If resetting the filters doesn't work, I can only repeat that Neil said, upgrade. IMO, using Joomla 1.5 is an invitation for your site to be hacked, particularly if you haven't applied the EOF hotfixes described by Neil. Use Redmigrator or something similar to transfer to 2.5, upgrade to 2.5.28 and then migrate to 3.x from there.